# Change the select tag from AntDesign

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next component in my application:

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const clear = () => setValue(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        mode={"multiple"}
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        allowClear={false}
        placeholder="PERMANENT TEXT"  //i want to make vissibile this text permanent even i select an item from select tag
        style={{ width: "200px" }}
        showSearch={false}
        //  defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
        <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
      </Select>
      <button onClick={clear}>reset</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const clear = () => setValue(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        mode={"multiple"}
        value={value}
        onChange={setValue}
        allowClear={false}
        placeholder="PERMANENT TEXT"  //i want to make vissibile this text permanent even i select an item from select tag
        style={{ width: "200px" }}
        showSearch={false}
        //  defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
        <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
      </Select>
      <button onClick={clear}>reset</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I try to achieve next:

 1. I try to make the placeholder visible  permanent when i open the application, but  now a tag still as the first item, but i want to hide it.
[image]

And to  show every time:

[image]

I tried `defaultActiveFirstOption={false}` but it does not happens.

2. When i will choose one of the option i don't want do output the value in Select input like this:
   [image]

   But i want to see `PERMANENT TEXT` like in the image before this.

   Question: How to achieve the the above targets?

    demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-ant-design-demo-03506?file=/index.js:186-787

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `useState(null);`. The default state should be undefined. You just need to change it to `useState();`

https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-ant-design-demo-mew2p

Comment: but what about the second target?

Comment: I don't really get the idea of your second target. The default behavior of the placeholder is just to show a text example and is cleared once the input is entered. If you need to show a description, you probably need a label to display that instead of trying to make a permanent placeholder.
If you really want to make that, I recommend not to use antdesign place holder, but make your own, and using css absolute styling to put it in the right place.